# Console log of AJAX data is my html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to transfer data through an ajax request. I want to transfer the contents of the input field. But output of `console.log("ok" + data)` is "ok" + all my html code, although output of `console.log("ok" + formData)` is that value i need.

respectively, in the Django view variable `q = None`

```html
<input id="search" name="q" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск">
<input name='submit_s' id='search_btn' type='button' value='poisk' />
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#search_btn").click(function () {
        var formData = $('#search').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "search/",
            data: {
                q: formData,
            },
            processData: false,
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != ''){
                    console.log("ok" + data);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("no");
                }
            },
            failure: function(data){
                console.log("FAIL");
                console.log(data);
            },

        });
    });
});
```

My views.py:

```
def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    print(q) # Output: q = None
    return render(request, 'myapp/new_topic.html', {'q':q} )
```

Comment: post your view code.

Comment: change GET to POST

Comment: If data type is JSON then replace datatype to contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",

Comment: Changing GET to POST did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same view to render the page and for the `GET` ajax request. You will get the your html page in your ajax request as well. You need to check if your is request is an ajax request. You need to do somethig like:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


def search(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    print(q) # Output: q = None
    if request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse({'q': q})
    return render(request, 'myapp/new_topic.html', {'q':q} )
```

From the docs: [HttpRequest.is_ajax()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax)

> Returns True if the request was made via an XMLHttpRequest, by
>   checking the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header for the string
>   'XMLHttpRequest'. Most modern JavaScript libraries send this header.

Answer (score 0):

At here you are facing problem

> processData: false

```
processData (default: true)
Type: Boolean
By default, data passed into the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) 
will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the 
default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". 
If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.
```

REF: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Hope This will help you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#search_btn").click(function () {
        var formData = {
            q: $('#search').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://google.com",
            data: formData,
            processData: true,
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != ''){
                    console.log("ok" + data);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("no");
                }
            },
            failure: function(data){
                console.log("FAIL");
                console.log(data);
            },

        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" name="q" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Поиск">
<input name='submit_s' id='search_btn' type='button' value='poisk' />
```